# Unicode POST parameters with Indy 10 and Delphi 6

Tags: indy10, delphi-6

I am using Indy 10 with Delphi 6 and until now managed to pass contents as UTF-8.

Unfortunately, params are parsed as ANSI, replacing, for example, ö with o when not the central european code page is the default.

Could I get POST request parameters at least as UTF-8 if I am not able to get WideString immediately?

```
procedure TTheServer._serverCommandGet(AContext: TIdContext;
  ARequestInfo: TIdHTTPRequestInfo; AResponseInfo: TIdHTTPResponseInfo); // Indy 10
begin
  ARequestInfo.Params.Values['ParamName']; // Returns ANSI in Delphi 6
end;
```

Comment: Are you using an up-to-date version of Indy? The `ARequestInfo.Params` is already parsed as UTF-8 by default. However, since the `Params` is a `TStrings` holding `AnsiString` values in Delphi 6, the decoded UTF-8 will be converted to the OS default codepage when stored in the `Params`. If the POST data is `%C3%B6` then you *should* be getting `ö` in the `Params` on a European system, but that's not guaranteed on other systems. There is currently no option to specify a different codepage for the decoded `AnsiString`s. If you need that, you can parse the `ARequestInfo.UnparsedParams` yourself.

Comment: @Remy Lebeau: Thank you for the support. I will try to parse `ARequestInfo.UnparsedParams` to bypass WideString to AnsiString conversion.

Comment: Look at the source code for `TIdHTTPRequestInfo.DecodeAndSetParams()` as a base. You would simply need to pass in the extra `ADestEncoding` parameter to `TIdURI.URLDecode()`, which is not currently being passed in, hence why the OS default is being used.